# Is there a way to change the lockscreen message/owner's info using ADB?

Tags: adb, lock-screens

My Realme 7 Pro doesn't support lockscreen messages for some reason but I was wondering if I could change my lockscreen message because when I first got my phone I backed it up immediately (Google Backup I think...) and my old cringey quote was on the lockscreen (it was horrible) and I couldn't remove it. Does anyone know what **ADB command** I need to type to **replace** my old quote? If you know other ways to replace it **without root** I will gladly accept it.